# How to make MUI autocomplete field where tags can be added in-between normal text with a # input?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make an MUI autocomplete field where I can write normal text, however, when the user inputs #, the autocomplete popper appears and the user can add a tag in between the normal text.

Comment: Do you have a sample code? I

Comment: @AhadRafatTalebi, I have no idea how I would do it in the first place using MUI. Hence, I don't have any sample code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.